# How to validate / check types using JSDoc?

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint, jsdoc

I'm looking for something like ESLint but that would actually validate types based on JSDoc `@param` tags. I tried [ts-node](/questions/tagged/ts-node) but it doesn't seem to enforce it. For example this doesn't throw:

```
/**
 * Adds
 * 
 * @param {number} numb1
 * @param {number} numb2
 * 
 * @returns {number}
 */
function add(numb1, numb2) {
  return numb1 + numb2
}

console.log(add('something', '234'))
```

Comment: I think you _may_ be looking for the [Google Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler)

Answer (score 3):

You can use typescript to check types inside a javascript file. You have to use tsconfig file and make 'checkJS' flag as true.
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-checking-javascript-files.html

Answer (score 2):

As per my comment and depending on your project configuration, you *could* use the [Google Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler) for that.

There's an online playground where people can toy with it. Here's what the compiler says when it tries to compile your code with the **advanced optimisation** turned on.

As you can see it's been able to infer from the JSDoc `@param` tags that the `add` function was called with unexpected parameter types:

[image]